# Late 70's or early 80's tv series - astronaut with enhanced senses

Tags: story-identification, tv

An astronaut on a space mission looks out of the shuttle window. Bright flash of light causes him to go blind. Back on Earth, he was healing and he began to regain his vision. He realized all of his 5 senses are heightened to a greater degree than the average person's. He's able to read license plates from a mile away, hear things others can't, and even his metabolism has risen to where he is able to run at the speed of a cheetah. From there I can't remember much more but being an 80's flick, I think he goes on to fight crime and help the weak and whatnot.

Comment: :) Two good questions that led to answers. Congrats!

Comment: That awesome! Can't believe it. Memory those been stuck in my head so long. Never been able to truely do away with constantly trying to remember titles. Thanks now I can maybe watch it see what all the fuss was about. Lol! Why this's stuck in my head so long. And best all I'll never have to struggle with  the reacurring memoir those two shows. Slam dunk right into my into my mobile trash can!  Lol!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is it possible you're thinking of the 1986 TV Movie, *[Northstar](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091650/)*?

[image: Northstar - Movie Image]

> Astronaut Jack North is hit by mysterious solar radiation while photographing an eclipse during a spacewalk. Returned to Earth, scientists find that as long as his eyes are exposed to the ultraviolet in sunlight, his mental and physical abilities are boosted to superhuman levels. More than a few minutes of exposure risks overload and death, so he needs to wear special sunglasses. Wearing the glasses or at night, he's a normal human. But in sunlight, he can think like a computer, recall everything, has super-senses and super-strength and can run as fast as a motorcycle. North uses his newfound abilities to investigate the murder of his best friend and fellow astronaut.

### Full film (trailer unavailable)

Found by searching for `tv series blinded astronaut enhanced senses`