# 80's Sci-Fi TV Movie About a Guy Whose Eyes Change Color as His Powers Increase

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I'm trying to find the name of an 80's sci-fi TV movie, possibly something that was intended as a pilot but was never picked up, that featured a guy, as I recall male Caucasian, who gained enhanced speed and strength that corresponded to his excitement levels. In other words, the more trouble he was in, the stronger and faster he would become.

The really notable thing about his abilities was that his eyes would change to three different colors, each representing tiered stages of his power increases: yellow, blue and finally red. (I remember the eyes being completely solid when he powered up. No pupils. Just solid yellow, blue or red. I don't *think* they glowed, but I could be mistaken on that point.)

The only scenes I can clearly remember are when the institute or scientists he worked with demonstrated to him how his powers worked using a manikin or "test dummy" that had a sectioned off part of its head to depict what his brain was doing as he progressed through each color/power level. The eyes and brain of the manikin would both turn colors as they ran the simulation.

Of note about that simulation was when the mankin's brain and eyes turned red for too long, its brain burst into flames. So they warned him that progressing past yellow and blue was potentially life threatening. They also told him that going through these colors subtracted some amount of time off his lifespan. (So, I guess, *all* of it was life threatening, really.)

The other scene I can remember is just a few seconds towards the end. I believe he's wrestling with the bad guy on a catwalk. I know the bad guy has him on his back and is about to kill him or something. And, for whatever reason, he goes through all three eye colors just to give the guy a shove that tosses him off the catwalk and to his death. I remember thinking it was completely unnecessary for him to go through all three eye colors, when yellow would have been enough strength for, like, one dude.

I *vaguely* remember a blurry, running fast scene. And I'm pretty sure there was a girl, as well as a guy in a lab coat as co-stars. I cannot remember any distinguishing characteristics about any of the actors. I'm not even positive they were all Caucasian, but that would have been common in the 80's. I think everyone was roughly in their 20's or 30's, but that's also iffy.

I distinctly remember this TV movie airing in the 80's, but I could easily be off by a few years in either direction. I don't remember this being a series, but maybe it was just a short lived one, and that's why my TV movie searches don't turn anything up.

Comment: Was this live-action or animated?  What country did you see it in, and what language was the movie?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or for frak's sake. I just did search for 80's TV series to see if I could help anyone else out, as that's a thing I've been researching lately, and it's literally the first thing I click on. I've been searching for this for three weeks. My first question, even.

The movie was called Northstar, and it was with freaking Greg Evigan.

[Late 70's or early 80's tv series - astronaut with enhanced senses](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168974/late-70s-or-early-80s-tv-series-astronaut-with-enhanced-senses)

I guess this can be closed as a duplicate, answered or whatever the policy is? I honestly didn't expect to find it just by searching "80's TV series".

Comment: I will mark it as a duplicate. Only you will be able to mark it as accepted (which you can't do until 48 hours after asking due to it being a self-answer) by clicking on the checkmark. But congrats on finding it!